# Пойск для сайта на php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица table, в ней есть столбцы id name text. Хочу в сайте сбоку поставить поиск, чтоб искал только по столбцу name с таблицы table и выводил примерно следующее

```
<a href='text'>name</a>
```

Может, кто делал и покажет, как сделал?

а есть весь процесс? смысле ВЕСЬ код который можно вставить в шаблон и файл который будет выводить итоги? или как его создать?

Спасибо.

Comment: Добавите меня в скайп node_xaker. Если будет время помогу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**html**

```
<form action="seach.php" method="POST">
  <p><b>Поиск</b></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="p" value="Найти..."/></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value='Найти'></p> 
</form>
```

**seach.php**

```
<?
$p = $_POST['p'];
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT id,name,text FROM `table` WHERE `name` = '.$p) or die (mysql_error()); 
print"<table width='100%'>";  
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
print "<tr><td width='5%'>".$r['id']."</td><td width='20%' align='center'>".$r['name']."</td><td width='75%'>".$r['text']."</td></tr>;
}
print"</table>";
?>
```

А если Вам надо type: `<a href='text'>name</a>`,
то тогда: **seach.php**

```
 <?
    $p = $_POST['p'];
    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT id,name,text FROM `table` WHERE `name` = '.$p) or die (mysql_error()); 
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
      print"<a href='".$r['text']."'>".$r['name']."</a>";
    }

    ?>
```

Писал на скорую руку

Comment: Дописал то что тебе надо

Answer (score 1):

Если с перезагрузкой страницы, то примерно так:

```
<?php
include 'search_form';
if (isset($_POST('search'))) { 
   include 'search_result';
}
?>
```

a запрос к базе примерно такой:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `name` FROM table WHERE `name` like %".$_POST['search']."%;";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Назабывайте обрамлять входящие данные, sql inj тут как тут :)